# push multidimensional array into json object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, multidimensional-array

I am trying to insert some data in my mongodb database and I require data in some specific format

```
var location1 = [2,3];
var location2 = [];
location2.push(location1);
location2.push(location1);
var location3 = [];
location3.push(location2);
console.log(location3);    //this is the format that i require for insert in mongodb

var couponData = {
        location:{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":location3},
        UsersTargetted:[],
};
console.log(couponData);
```

But while running the code i get output as:

```
{ location: { type: 'Polygon', coordinates: [ [Object] ] },
  UsersTargetted: [] }
```

So, how to make coordinates value as given below:
[ [ [ 2, 3 ], [ 2, 3 ] ] ]

Thanks

Update:
I am not inserting anything in mongodb but creating a json object so that I can insert that object in the mongodb. My requirement is that coordinates field in json object should have value shown above. However, when I insert location3 variable, my console doesn`t show the location3 value, instead it is showing [[object]].

Update2:
Thanks Anand. data is getting stored in mongodb as expected. So no issue, maybe some problem in nodeeclipse.

Comment: I think the output is correct. At least it worked with me.

Comment: You get output from where?  Node, mongo, client-side JS?

Comment: I am using nodeeclipse console for output. I checked with terminal also, [object], still showed up

Comment: This does not even show an insert/update operation at all. What are you actually trying? Please update so people can see you problem.

Comment: @DaniloValente You got the correct output? Where did you run that>?

Comment: I ran it in the Mongo Shell and got the correct output.  You should try to insert the data into MongoDB and look at the document.

Answer (score 0):

If you are really worried about it then:

```
console.log( JSON.stringify( location3 );
```

And that should clear it up, showing the correct nested format.

Oddly, the syntax is documented as the way to do it [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/geoWithin/#geowithin)